# Trouble with INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, sql, insert, oledb

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting a `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`.

The code is below.

```
static void ABSChangeEventsTable(string ControlNumber, string CurrentStatus)
{
   using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConnAbstracting))
   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      connection.Open();               

      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Events (Date_Time, Details, Regarding, User, Control_Number) VALUES (@Date_Time, @Details, @Regarding, @User, @Control_Number)";

      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Time", DateTime.Now);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", "OLD:"+CurrentStatus+" NEW: Received Fax");
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regarding", "Status Changed");
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", "System");
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Control_Number", ControlNumber);

      try
      {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {                   
         throw;
      }
   }            
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User` is a reserved keyword, you need to wrap it in square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO Events (Date_Time, Details, Regarding, [User], Control_Number) VALUES (@Date_Time, @Details, @Regarding, @User, @Control_Number)
```

I'd recommend renaming that column to avoid the need for square brackets every time you reference it.

Comment: Now i'm getting a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: In order of how they appear in my INSERT statement -- (Date/Time, Memo, Text, Text, Number)

Comment: My guess would be that the `@Date_Time` parameter is being passed in the wrong format (e.g. dd-mm-yyy when it should be mm-dd-yyyy or vice-versa).

Comment: Yep. I changed it to `DateTime.Now.ToString()` --works fine now. Thanks for the help!